# In ios, Frames extracted from FHD (1920 x 1080) video file is HD (1280 x 720) image

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, camera, video-processing

I am writing iphone app, which analyzes video.
The target video is recorded with back camera of iphone at 240 fps in FHD. (1920 x 1080)

First I extracted a frame from the video.   The frame image is always HD (1280 x 720)

I do need FHD.   To get FHD image from FHD video, I tried two method.   Both failed.

BTW, I found an iphone app called Frame Grabber.  It extracts a frame from a video.  The generated image was FHD.  Thus, I think there IS a way to extract FHD image.

One is using typical swift code like this.

```
func extract_frames(start_frame_num: Int, number_of_frames: Int) {
        guard let videoURL = selectedVideoURL else {
            print("No video URL found")
            return
        }
        

        guard let assetReader = try? AVAssetReader(asset: asset) else {
            print("Could not create AVAssetReader")
            return
        }

        let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first!
        let readerOutputSettings: [String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB)]
        
        let assetReaderOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: videoTrack, outputSettings: readerOutputSettings)

        
        if assetReader.canAdd(assetReaderOutput) {
            assetReader.add(assetReaderOutput)
        } else {
            print("Couldn't add reader output")
            return
        }

        let frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: Int32(videoTrack.nominalFrameRate))
        let startFrameTime = CMTimeMultiply(frameDuration, multiplier: Int32(start_frame_num))
        
        // Set the time range before starting to read
        assetReader.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: startFrameTime, duration: asset.duration)

        assetReader.startReading()

        var currentFrame = start_frame_num

        frames.removeAll()
        print("existing frames are all removed.")
        // Extract frames
        while currentFrame < (start_frame_num + number_of_frames) {
            guard let sampleBuffer = assetReaderOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() else {
                break
            }
            
            if let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
                // Convert to UIImage
                let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
                let context = CIContext(options: nil)
                if let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) {
                    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
                    frames.append(uiImage)
                    print("Extracted frame \(currentFrame)")
                }
            }

            currentFrame += 1
        }

        assetReader.cancelReading()
    }
```

The other way is using opencv.
I tried a similar opencv code in macbook.  It successfully extracted FHD image from the same FHD slow video.  However, this swift code using opencv also failed.

```
func extractFrames(startFrameNum: Int = 0, videoNum: Int = 1) {
        guard let videoURL = selectedVideoURL else {
            print("No video URL found")
            return
        }

        let videoCapture = VideoCapture(filename: videoURL.path)

        if !videoCapture.isOpened() {
            print("Error: Could not open video.")
            return
        }
        
        print("videoCapture width : \(videoCapture.get(propId: VideoCaptureProperties.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH.rawValue))")
        print("videoCapture height: \(videoCapture.get(propId: VideoCaptureProperties.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT.rawValue))")

        var frameCount = 0
        let frameToStop = startFrameNum + videoNum

        while videoCapture.grab() {
            if frameCount >= startFrameNum && frameCount < frameToStop {
                let mat = Mat()
                if videoCapture.retrieve(image: mat, flag: 0) {
                    let uiImage = mat.toUIImage()
                    self.frames.append(uiImage)
                    print("Frame at position \(frameCount) was saved.")
                }
            }
            frameCount += 1
        }
        print("\(videoURL.path) extraction completed. \(videoNum) frames extracted.\(frameCount) frames existed in this video. ")
    }
```

Both failed.  The resulting frame image is always HD.

Comment: opencv is only using platform apis. if the platform apis can't do it, that's their issue.

Comment: Check the `ciImage.extent`. What size did you get?